# php sessions and POST or GET variables

Tags: php, session

hi I have problems with sessions of php, i have a  page with a file where I created a session and sends to other page, in this page  receives `POST` or `GET` variables for do a search, but if I go to ahead and then back my navigator internet shows "confirm forwarding form "

```
session_start();    
if($_SESSION['logged']!='yes'){
    header('location: http://www.midomain.com/login.php');
}
else{
    $user=$_SESSION['user'];
    $varforsearch=$_POST['var'];        
}
```

if I delete the line `session_start();` it works , and doesnt show "confirm forwarding form ", if I go  ahead and then back, but doesnt create the session, any idea?

Comment: The webbrowser asks you this because you submitted a form, and he wants to know if you want to re-post the same data.

Comment: but if I remove the line session_start(); doesn't asks me nothing and it works!

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['logged']!='yes'` means session is not created , and user is not logged in.

and in else part you have written , `$user=$_SESSION['user'];`.

Normally , $_SESSION['logged'] should be true only if user is logged in successfully.

You should start assigning session value in authentication function , if user is validated , then only assign session variables.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, Can I create the variable to search like a session variable?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid resubmission you will need to redirect to same page.
Try this approach:

```
session_start();    
if($_SESSION['logged']!='yes'){
    header('location: http://www.midomain.com/login.php');
}
else{
    $user=$_SESSION['user'];
    $varforsearch=$_POST['var'];
    //Clear POST data
    unset($_POST);
    //redirect to your self or other page
    header('location: http://www.midomain.com/search.php');
}
```

Comment: actually I use the same page for search to show the results from the search, I have a page that I sends me to a page called "search.php" , here I write mi search,in this page I catch the word to search(with post), if the variable is different from empty   do the search, if my search finds something shows it in the same page

Comment: @undertakerevil yes I get that, have you try redirecting to the same page? that could possibly avoid the issue you are having